# Opencv, renew "first" frame

Tags: python, opencv

I followed a tutorial on opencv motion detection. I found the code in several sites, it's more or less the same: in a while loop, after having caught the first frame as base frame, find the difference comparing it to the next others.

I want to renew the first frame every 15 mins (thinking about light conditions during the day) but I cant understand why after taking the "new" first frame the process doesn't work anymore.

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils.video import VideoStream
import argparse
import datetime
import imutils
import time
import cv2

# construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video", help="path to the video file")
ap.add_argument("-a", "--min-area", type=int, default=500, help="minimum area size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
# if the video argument is None, then we are reading from webcam
if args.get("video", None) is None:
vs = VideoStream(src=0).start()
time.sleep(2.0)
# otherwise, we are reading from a video file
else:
    vs = cv2.VideoCapture(args["video"])
# initialize the first frame in the video stream
firstFrame = None
interval = datetime.datetime.now()
# loop over the frames of the video
while True:
    # grab the current frame and initialize the occupied/unoccupied
    # text
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = frame if args.get("video", None) is None else frame[1]

    text = "Unoccupied"
    # if the frame could not be grabbed, then we have reached the end
    # of the video
    if frame is None:
        break
    # resize the frame, convert it to grayscale, and blur it
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (21, 21), 0)
    # if the first frame is None, initialize it
    if firstFrame is None:
        firstFrame = gray
        continue

    # compute the absolute difference between the current frame and
    # first frame
    frameDelta = cv2.absdiff(firstFrame, gray)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(frameDelta, 25, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
    # dilate the thresholded image to fill in holes, then find contours
    # on thresholded image
    thresh = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=2)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
    # loop over the contours
    for c in cnts:
        # if the contour is too small, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) < args["min_area"]:
            continue
        # compute the bounding box for the contour, draw it on the frame,
        # and update the text
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        text = "Occupied"



    # draw the text and timestamp on the frame
    cv2.putText(frame, "Room Status: {}".format(text), (10, 20),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    cv2.putText(frame, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%A %d %B %Y %I:%M:%S%p"),
            (10, frame.shape[0] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.35, (0, 0, 255), 1)
    # show the frame and record if the user presses a key
    cv2.imshow("Security Feed", frame)
    cv2.imshow("Thresh", thresh)
    cv2.imshow("Frame Delta", frameDelta)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # if the `q` key is pressed, break from the lop
    if key == ord("q"):
        break
    # cleanup the camera and close any open windows


    if (datetime.datetime.now() - interval) > datetime.timedelta(minutes=15):
        firstFrame = None
vs.stop() if args.get("video", None) is None else vs.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: reset interval as well when you update firstFrane, otherwise you will update firstFrame in every iteration after the first 15 minutes.

Comment: You are right, thank you very much